# How can i reduce if-else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Are there are another ways to reduce this if-else statement? This code will change picture by got integers from database. I try to reduce this code.

```
  if (val["soil_h"] < 21){
       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground1.png');
    } else if (val["soil_h"] < 42){
       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground2.png');
    } else if (val["soil_h"] < 63){
       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground3.png');
    } else if (val["soil_h"] < 84){
       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground4.png');
    } else if (val["soil_h"] < 105){
       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground5.png');
    } else if (val["soil_h"] < 126){
       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground6.png');
    } else if (val["soil_h"] < 147){
       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground7.png');
    } else {
       $("$ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground8.png');
    }
```

Comment: Use switch : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki But you cannot use `case` statements with ranges of values...

Comment: var v = [21,42,63,84,105,126,147];
var count=1;
if(val["soil_h"] in v){
$("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground'+count+'.png');
count++;
}
else{
$("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground'+count+'.png');
}

Comment: Often I find when I am doing this, I am thinking in the wrong way. Why not have the database just return the image as well? Or have an object that have these integers as a key and the image as a value etc.

Comment: `val["soil_h"]` is an object.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko it is possible to use `case` with range of values, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35722632/1006854)

Comment: @mef that example uses `case` with boolean statements =) Besides, it's even longer than the original answer due to all the breaks, so it's not really "reducing" the original code.

Comment: @Papa.John please consider marking one of the answers as accepted—normally, it would be the one that helped you the most.

Answer (score 5):

> Use `/`(division) as all the values are multiple of `21`

Try this:

```
var value=val["soil_h"]/21;
$("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground"'+(value % 1 === 0 ? value : 8)+'".png'); //If value is not multiple of 21, default image is set..
```

Answer (score 3):

One way that comes to mind is to chain ternary operators:

```
var soil = val["soil_h"];

var imagePath =
    soil < 21  ? 'pic/ground1.png' :
    soil < 42  ? 'pic/ground2.png' :
    soil < 63  ? 'pic/ground3.png' :
    soil < 84  ? 'pic/ground4.png' :
    soil < 105 ? 'pic/ground5.png' :
    soil < 126 ? 'pic/ground6.png' :
    soil < 147 ? 'pic/ground7.png' :
                 'pic/ground8.png';

$("#ground").attr('src', imagePath);
```

Comment: The selector should probably be `$("#ground")` instead of `$("$ground")`

Comment: Thank for your suggestion @Dmytro Shevchenko

Answer (score 2):

**Looking close to your code I visualise its only the multiple of 21. So this is what I wrote assuming val["soil_h"] is always a number.**

> Simple mathematics

```
       var x = parseInt(val["soil_h"]/21);
      if(x==0){
       x=1;
      }else if(x>8){
        x=8;
      }


       $("#ground").attr('src', 'pic/ground'+x+'.png');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @zakaiter

Answer (score 1):

```js
var val = {
  soil_h: 43
};

var pics = [
  { url: 'pic/ground1.png', maxHeight: 21 },
  { url: 'pic/ground2.png', maxHeight: 42 },
  { url: 'pic/ground3.png', maxHeight: 63 },
  { url: 'pic/ground4.png', maxHeight: 84 },
  { url: 'pic/ground5.png', maxHeight: 105 },
  { url: 'pic/ground6.png', maxHeight: 126 },
  { url: 'pic/ground7.png', maxHeight: 147 },
  { url: 'pic/ground8.png', maxHeight: Number.MAX_VALUE },
];

$("#ground").attr('src', pics.find(function(pic) {
  return val["soil_h"]  < pic.maxHeight;
}).url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="ground" />
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) has limited compatibility

Comment: Its a simple mathematics you don't need to write too much code. Look below my answer

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Bob Sponge and everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using `switch`:

```
var imageName
    , soil = val["soil_h"]

switch(true) {
    case soil < 21:
        imageName = 'ground1.png'
        break
    case soil < 42:
        imageName = 'ground2.png'
        break
    case soil < 63:
        imageName = 'ground3.png'
        break
    case soil < 84:
        imageName = 'ground4.png'
        break
    case soil < 105:
        imageName = 'ground5.png'
        break
    case soil < 126:
        imageName = 'ground6.png'
        break
    case soil < 147:
        imageName = 'ground7.png'
        break
    default:
        imageName = 'ground8.png'
        break
}

$('#ground').attr('src', 'pic/' + imageName )
```

P.S. be aware that the selector of the last statement in the code you have shared looks incorrect: should probably be `$("#ground")` instead of `$("$ground")`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion@mef